# Python: gathering corresponding lines that meet certain condition from multiple files

Tags: python, file, loops, with-statement

I have a set of text files of the same line count and structure. For simplicity's sake, suppose they look something like this:

File 1:

```
2
3
34
56
```

File 2:

```
3
43
2
1
```

File 3:

```
9
88
3
11
```

For each line number (four in this case), I want to create a dictionary whose key is the number and whose value is a list containing the corresponding lines in my files that meet a certain condition.

For example, if the condition was that the number on the line should be greater than 10, the result would be:

```
1: []
2: [43, 88]
3: [34]
4: [56, 11]
```

I tried coding it like this:

```
meta_list = dict.fromkeys(range(0, num_lines), [])

for file in files:
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
          line_num = 1 
          for line in f:
              if condition_met(line):
                  meta_list[line_num].append(float(line))   
              line_num = line_num + 1
```

But my logic must be off! The result on my example data is a bunch of identical dicts! :

```
1: [34, 56, 43, 88, 11]
2: [34, 56, 43, 88, 11]
3: [34, 56, 43, 88, 11]
4: [34, 56, 43, 88, 11]
```

I've gone over this for quite a while and am baffled. Maybe it's obvious, but what am I missing here?

Comment: `dict.fromkeys` should be used only with immutable values.

Comment: But is that somehow the source of my problem?

Comment: Yep. all of the `[]`s you populated `meta_list` with in the first line are the same identical list. appending to one of them appends to all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
meta_list = dict((i, []) for i in range(0, num_lines))

for file in files:
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
          line_num = 1 
          for line in f:
              if condition_met(line):
                  meta_list[line_num].append(float(line))   
              line_num = line_num + 1
```

This creates a new list instance for `meta_list`.

Also check out `collections.defaultdict`, with that, your code becomes:

```
from collections import defaultdict

meta_list = defaultdict(list)

for file in files:
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
          line_num = 1 
          for line in f:
              if condition_met(line):
                  meta_list[line_num].append(float(line))   
              line_num = line_num + 1
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting `defaultdict`. I'd also use `enumerate` to count the line numbers as part of the `for` loop, rather than incrementing `line_num` manually.